# How to use declare/define @patch once and use it in every unit test inside a test class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have a case in code where I have to extract data from multiple database table. I have been using `patch` from `mock package` to write unit test cases. Wile mocking the database in test cases, I am using patch in every single test and there are around 10-15 tests for each class. Is there any way we can declare the `@patch` once and assigned it to the variable and use the variable rather than using `@patch` in every single test.
Example:

```
@patch("py-repo.module.class.get_data_from_db_1",
           side_effect=mock_method1)
@patch("py-repo.module.class.get_data_from_db_2",
           side_effect=mock_method2)
@patch("py-repo.module.class.get_data_from_db_3",
           side_effect=mock_method3)
def test_case_1(self, mock_1, mock_2, mock_3):
    self.assertEqual("some outputs",object("some inputs"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) is very flexible. You're currently using it as a function decorator, but it can also be a class decorator. It will then expect every test method on that class to accept the same mock objects.

If you don't want to declare arguments for every test method, you can also call a patcher's [`start()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) from a test class's `setUp()` method, and store the mock object in a member variable. Just be sure to use [`addCleanup()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup) to call `stop()`.

One more option: write a custom [context lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) that uses all the patches in a with block, and yields back to the test method.